# How to upload a file to the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to adapt the [ImportExportExcelASPNetCore // github.com](https://github.com/talkingdotnet/ImportExportExcelASPNetCore) project for the Asp.Net Framework.

**Question.**
1. How to adapt this fragment so that you do not need to redo the rest of the code?
Well, or to require a minimum alteration.

**Description.**
I use:

- [ImportExport.cshtml.cs](https://github.com/talkingdotnet/ImportExportExcelASPNetCore/blob/master/ImportExportExcelASPNetCore/Pages/ImportExport.cshtml.cs);
- [ImportExport.cshtml](https://github.com/talkingdotnet/ImportExportExcelASPNetCore/blob/master/ImportExportExcelASPNetCore/Pages/ImportExport.cshtml).

**Controller of my project**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

// 
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Hosting;

// using Microsoft.

namespace WebAppFrm.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult OnPostImport()
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string folderName = "Upload";
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string sFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
                ISheet sheet;
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    if (sFileExtension == ".xls")
                    {
                        HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read the Excel 97-2000 formats  
                        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        XSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read 2007 Excel format  
                        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook   
                    }

                    IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0); //Get Header Row
                    int cellCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;
                    sb.Append("<table class='table'><tr>");
                    for (int j = 0; j < cellCount; j++)
                    {
                        NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICell cell = headerRow.GetCell(j);
                        if (cell == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.ToString())) continue;
                        sb.Append("<th>" + cell.ToString() + "</th>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                    for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++) //Read Excel File
                    {
                        IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
                        if (row == null) continue;
                        if (row.Cells.All(d => d.CellType == CellType.Blank)) continue;
                        for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
                        {
                            if (row.GetCell(j) != null)
                                sb.Append("<td>" + row.GetCell(j).ToString() + "</td>");
                        }
                        sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</table>");
                }
            }
            return this.Content(sb.ToString());
        }




    }
}
```

In code snippet

```
IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string folderName = "Upload";
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
```

I get errors:

1. "NameValueCollection" does not contain the definition of "Files", and could not find an available extension method "Files", accepting type "NameValueCollection" as the first argument (possibly using directive or assembly reference is missing).

   2. The name "_hostingEnvironment" does not exist in the current context.
   3. Could not find the type or namespace name "IFormFile" (there may be a missing using directive or assembly reference).

[image]

---

### Update-1

I installed - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`.
I installed - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`.

**Errors left**

1. "NameValueCollection" does not contain the definition of "Files",
   and could not find an available extension method "Files", accepting
   type "NameValueCollection" as the first argument (possibly using
   directive or assembly reference is missing).
2. The name "_hostingEnvironment" does not exist in the current
   context.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### Update 2

Installed `System.Collections.Specialized`.
Pressed - F6.

Did not help.

---

### Update 3

The purpose of this question:
 - create an application that can import Excel file.
I took the project from `github.com` as the basis.
In the controller, I get errors in the place of the code where the file is downloaded to the server.
How to fix the code so that you can upload the file to the server?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to do. Can you explain a little bit more? Do you want to adopt code from .NET Core to .NET?

Comment: @GlacialMan  The purpose of this question:
 - create an application that can import Excel file.
I took the project from `github.com` as the basis.
In the controller, I get errors.
How to fix the code so that you can upload the file to the server?
I need to solve a problem with uploading a file to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed all the required package for this project?

- For IFormFile we need to include namespace **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http**

  NuGet Command `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http -Version 2.2.2`
- For Hosting environment-class **System.Web.Hosting**

  NuGet Command `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting -Version 2.2.7`

Hope this will help.

Comment: See **Update-1**

Comment: I think the root problem is "NameValueCollection", System.Collections.Specialized contain "System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection",  Please Install the following package.
___________________
Install-Package System.Collections.Specialized -Version 4.3.0

Comment: Installed `System.Collections.Specialized`.
Pressed - F6.
Did not help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the main part of code for copying files to the server. You didn't declare object _hostingEnviroment so because of that you have the error. And you can't combine .NET Core and .NET Framework.